# Retrofit @Patch method (Updating an object, which contains an ArrayList)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

Note: Newbie here, please let me know if i need to provide more information or clarify on anything.

To give you some context: I am practising building a Messenger-clone application with lots of Retrofit methods. For that purpose, i am using a small local JSON server, with which the application communicates.

When a user of the application creates an account, the application creates a profile object in the JSON server using the following method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("profiles")
suspend fun createProfile(@Field("username") username: String?,
                            @Field("picture") picture: String?,
                            @Field(value = "nickname") nickname: String?,
                            @Field(value = "contacts") contacts: ArrayList<String?>,
                            @Field(value = "status") status: Int?): Response<Profile>
```

Initially, the contacts ArrayList is empty, because the user has not yet added any contacts. Creating a random profile with an empty ArrayList() for the contacts parameter, this is the result inside the JSON server:

```
{
    "username": "username.example",
    "picture": "picture's URL",
    "nickname": "Nikola",
    "status": 1,
    "id": 4
}
```

The class that represents the Profile model inside the application is this:

```
class Profile(
    val username: String? = "",
    var picture: String? = "",
    var nickname: String? = "",
    var contacts: ArrayList<String?>? = ArrayList(),
    var status: Int? = 1,
    val id: Int? = 0
)
```

Once the profile is created, naturally the user can add new contacts, which happens using the following method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("profiles/{id}")
suspend fun addContact(@Path("id") id: Int?,
                        @Field("contacts") contacts: ArrayList<String?>?): Response<Profile>
```

And here is where the problem occurs, on the very first contact added. The ArrayList, which is sent to server contains just one item and the result inside the JSON server looks like this:

```
{
    "username": "username.example",
    "picture": "picture's URL",
    "nickname": "Nikola",
    "status": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "contacts": "first.contact"
}
```

Basically, because the arraylist contains just one item, it saves it as a String. This creates all kinds of problems later on because, once the application uses a @GET method for that profile, it expects an ArrayList for the contacts attribute, but it receives a String.

What can i do to make the the JSON profile look like this:

```
{
    "username": "username.example",
    "picture": "picture's URL",
    "nickname": "Nikola",
    "status": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "contacts": ["first.contact"]
}
```

The contacts parameter needs to be an array, even when there is only one item in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Body` instead of `@Form` and `@FormUrlEncoded`:

```
data class ProfileContacts(val contacts: List<String>)

@PATCH("profiles/{id}")
suspend fun addContact(@Path("id") id: Int?, @Body contacts: ProfileContacts): Response<Profile>
```

and add a converter, if you haven't already had one, a [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) one for example:

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1' // latest version
}
```

```
// Retrofit Builder
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    ... // other methods
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
```

`@Body` lets you define the request body as a Kotlin class, which will eventually get serialized using the provided `Converter` (in case of Gson, it will be converted to JSON). `@Field` on the other hand is used for sending data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (as the required `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation also suggests). This means that the body of your request will be encoded into a list of key-value pairs, separated by '&', e.g. (based on the `createProfile` method):

```
username=username.example&picture=picture%27s%20URL&nickname=Nikola&status=1&id=4
```

You can POST an array as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by using the same key more than once. That's what basically happens when you annotate a list with the Retrofit `@Field` annotation - every element from the list is paired with the common key, e.g.:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PATCH("profiles/{id}")
suspend fun addContact(@Path("id") id: Int?,
                       @Field("contacts") contacts: ArrayList<String?>?): Response<Profile>

// ...
addContact(1, arrayListOf("first.contact", "second.contact"))

// request body:
contacts=first.contact&contacts=second.contact
```

So when you try to update the profile using only one element `contacts` list, a single "contacts" pair gets created (`contacts=first.contact`), and it's treated like a string value.